# Why does my vsc terminal fail to execute command?

Tags: node.js, angular

When I try to run my app with the command nx run hub:serve, the terminal inside vsc fails to execute it.

[image]

But when I run the same command in cmd, everything is okay.

[image]

This happens only inside vsc, with both cmd and powershell terminals

Comment: Your terminal in VSC is PowerShell. If you run the script in the PS outside of VSC does it fail as well? If so, the first thing would be global variables set in both shells.

Answer (score 0):

there is a strict standard limit for the memory usage in every node Project,
if you do not increase it manually. this error will be there so run this command to increase memory usage

1. export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096
2. npm start